# Set domain to a second level relation in odoo 10

Tags: odoo, odoo-domain

Basically, i have 3 models:

[A] - one2many -> [B] - one2many -> [C]

When a field in model A change, Model B dropdown of C elements should be filtered by some domain.

How can i do that?

More specific. In Inventory / Dashboard -> Click on Internal Transfers -> Create a new one, then:

[see inventory movement form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhvA1.png)

Answer (score 0):

Let try add a domain to your Initial Demand-> Product fields like:

> < field name='product'
>   domain="[('source_location','=',parent.source_location[0][2] or
>   False/>

If source_location is a field in Product object

Comment: It's not. The models involved are stock.picking and stock.move. stock.move is the one with product_id. I'm modifying the form of stock.picking. stock.picking its related with stock.move by an one2many relation in the field move_lines. I was trying not to modify stock.move. Anyway the domain i need to calculate is a complex one. It should be done by a python function.